# Access Calculated fields if statement

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to have a calculated field where some of the columns are not calculated?

with not calculated I mean that some of the data needs to be calculated and some of the data needs to be put in by hand

I have already tried it with an IIF statement like this

```
IIf( [Uitkomst] = 0 , [Lengte] * [Breedte] * [Hoogte] , [Uitkomst])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you by "not calculated" mean *Null*, you can use *Nz* for these empty fields:

```
IIf([Uitkomst] = 0, Nz([Lengte]) * Nz([Breedte]) * Nz([Hoogte]), [Uitkomst])
```

Query:

```sql
Select 
    *, IIf([Uitkomst] = 0, [Lengte] * [Breedte] * [Hoogte], [Uitkomst]) 
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: that is not what i mean but i have edited my question to formulate the question better

Comment: No. For that, you must use a _select query_ with parameters for the manual input. In general, avoid calculated fields in tables; queries are for this.